# How to fix an ever going redirection process?

Tags: php, mysql, redirect, include

I have a little problem. Here is my example:

file1.php :

```
<?php include("file2.php"); ?>
```

file2.php :

```
<?php header("Location: file1.php"); ?>
```

Because file2.php is included the redirection process will never end. But I still want the file2.php to redirect to file1.php and I also need to include file2.php in file1.php.

It may sound a bit complicated, but I think it can be solved.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Best Regards,

Akos

Comment: you are in circle path that never end without a condition you will definitely travel this circle infinitely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap the redirection statement in an if statement like this:

```
// file2.php
<?php
if ($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] == "file2.php") {
    header("Location: file1.php");
}
?>
```

You can also detect include with something like this:

```
if (realpath(__FILE__) == realpath($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']) {
    // Not Included
} else {
    // Included
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Only redirect in file2.php if you are not already on file1.php:

`if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] != "/file1.php") {
    header("Location: /file1.php");
}`

Another possible solution is to use a flag that signals that file2 should only be included:

- In file1.php: `define('INCLUDE_MODE', true);`
- Inf file2.php: `if (!INCLUDE_MODE) {header("Location: /file1.php"); exit;}`